# create randome movement in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to create game like rock paper scissors in flutter :
i like to have 5 object for each ,like 5 papers , 5 rock and 5 scissors  .
We will randomly drop these objects on our screen After that, these objects will start moving in a random direction. These objects will bounce off the wall if they hit the wall (we consider screen boundaries as walls) . If two objects collide, two things can happen:
If two objects are of the same type e.g. two rocks, then they will bounce. If two objects are not of the same type, one of them will be removed from the screen and the winner will bounce e.g. if a rock collides with a scissor, the rock will win, the scissor will be removed and the rock will bounce and move in the opposite direction.

i didnt find any package yet

Comment: Check https://docs.flame-engine.org/latest/

Answer (score 1):

This question is way to large to ask. You are asking how to make a complete game.

Try to take it with small steps

- set up development env
- Get something on the screen
- Think of the systems you need
- Start implementing the basics

And go from there. You cant just ask how to make a complete game here.

Good luck!